# How can I make p:selectOneMenu updates bean?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

```
<h:form>

  <h:panelGrid columns="2" style="margin-bottom:10px" cellpadding="5">
    <p:outputLabel for="providerSelect" value="Provider:" />
    <p:selectOneMenu id="providerSelect" value="#{programsController.provider}" style="width:125px">
      <p:ajax event="change" listener="#{programsController.providerSelected}" update="programsTable" />
      <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select Provider" itemValue="" />
      <f:selectItems value="#{providersController.providers}" var="provider" itemLabel="#{provider.name} (#{provider.uri})" />
      <f:converter binding="#{providerConverter}"/>
    </p:selectOneMenu>
  </h:panelGrid>

</h:form>
```

programsController.setProvider is not invoked.

The converter's `getAsObject` executed three times once for property value, and the two times with empty string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update2:** Your converter now also gets the empty String of the single selectItem.

You could add this part to your converters getAsObject Method:

```
if(value.length() == 0) return null;
```

You also need a method in the object class to verify if it is correct. Here's an example, replace getId() by the unique identifier of your provider objects.

```
//for converter check if the object is valid
public boolean equals(Object o){

if (o == this) return true;
    if(o instanceof Provider) {
        if(
           this.getId() == ((Provider)o).getId()){
               return true;
           }else{
               return false;
           }

    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Update:** This part is not correct anymore, because the question was updated

Your ajax event doesn't process the value, you only update the components.

Just add process="@this" to the ajax event, then it will process the value to the bean:

```
<p:ajax event="change" update="@this programsTable" process="@this"/>
```

Comment: You should provide your bean, converter and the provider class if the converter ist the problem now.